# Prove the order of $h$ when $h \in G\ \langle g \rangle$, $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group that is not cyclic

Tags: p-groups

The lemma to be proved is:

Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group that is not cyclic. Suppose that $g \in G$ has maximal order. If $h \in G \setminus \langle g \rangle$ has smallest possible order, then $|h| = p$.

And the proof is written as:

Let $g \in G$ be of maximal order in $G$, say $|g| = p^m$ for some $m \le n$. Since $G$ is not cyclic, $G \neq \langle g \rangle$. Choose  $h \in G \setminus \langle g \rangle$ where $h$ has smallest possible order, say $|h|=p^l$. Since $e \in \langle g \rangle$, then $h \neq e$ and so $l > 0$. But $|h^p|=p^{l-1}$ and so **$|h^p|$ has smaller order than $|h|$, whence $h^p \in \langle g \rangle$**.

What I could not understand is the bolded line: how can we say that  $h^p \in \langle g \rangle$ because $|h^p|$ has smaller order than $|h|$?

Comment: Is $\langle g\rangle$ the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$? And if so, what is $G\langle g\rangle$? Do you mean $G \setminus \langle g\rangle$ (the set of elements of $G$ not in $\langle g\rangle$?

Comment: You are right. Typo is corrected.

Comment: If order of $h$ is $p$, we are done. If order of $h$ is $p^2$, what it means? $h^{p^2}=1$ but no smaller positive power is $1$. Now, what is order of $h^p$? It is $p$ - why? $(h^p)^p=1$. So, $h^p$ is an element of order $p$, which is less than the smallest possible order of element in $G\setminus \langle g\rangle$; so $h^p$ should lie inside $\langle g\rangle$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We chose $h$ to be an element of $G \setminus \langle g\rangle$ whose order is as small as possible.

Therefore if $h^p$ has smaller order than $h$, $h^p$ cannot be an element of $G \setminus \langle g\rangle$: otherwise, we would have chosen $h^p$ instead of $h$. This means it must be an element of $\langle g\rangle$.